# Azure Service Bus + Xamarin Forms - Is this possible?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azureservicebus

I have mobile app in Xamarin Forms (**Android**), it need an offline mode thus I've created a concept of delayed events with API communication. 
Instead of making my own **queue** I d like to rely on some robust solution such as MS Azure Bus. I've already done a subscibers in backend side, but unfourtunatly WindowsAzure.ServiceBus can not be installed in Xmaarin side "Please note that this package requires **.Net Framework 4.5.2**.".

Is there any possibility to use some azure mobile SDK for publishing messages in xamarin app?

Any reply will be apprecied :)

Comment: I'm also struggling to get Azure Service Bus integrated with my Xamarin. Android emulator. I couldn't publish to the service bus directly from the Android emulator. Instead, I had delegate that operation to a web service in order to publish to the service bus.

I have a feeling that I will not be able to subscribe to a service bus from Android either.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) package that is targeted for .NET Standard.

Comment: You are right! Found it by myself a moment ago. I didn't find any info about this in docs. Sorry guys for waste of time and thx anyway!

Comment: I haven't been able to get this working on Xamarin.Android.
My automated tests publishes messages to Azure Function via a ServiceBusTrigger every time. However it fails in my Xamarin app.